# Make generic model save method

Tags: python, django

I have the following save method for the `Catalog` model:

```
class Catalog:
    ...
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            log.error('NOT ALLOWING SAVE OF %s' % self.__class__.__name__)
        else:
            super(Catalog, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Is there a way to make:

```
super(Catalog, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

More generic, so I don't have to hardcode `Catalog` in there, and I can use this for any model without any modification?

Comment: I'm not quite clear the use case you want. Do you want to make it so that you can copy/paste the code w/o having to change anything? Because anything derived from Catalog will be able to use this save method just fine as is.

Comment: @CrazyCasta that's correct -- so I can copy/paste the code without making any changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be copying and pasting code between classes. That misses the whole point of the vital principle of Don't Repeat Yourself (DRY).

Instead, make this a method on a separate class which you can use as a mixin.

```
class SavePrevented(object):
    ...
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            log.error('NOT ALLOWING SAVE OF %s' % self.__class__.__name__)
        else:
            super(SavePrevented, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

and use it when you define any other model:

```
class Catalog(SavePrevented, models.Model):
    ...
```

Comment: It should be `SavePrevented` in `class Catalog`.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to create a `pre_save` function that will error on any of those models.

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
@receiver(pre_save)
def refuse_creation(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    FORBIDDEN_MODELS = ['Table1', 'Table2', ...]
    cls_name = instance.__class__.__name__
    if cls_name in FORBIDDEN_MODELS:
        if not instance.pk:
            log.error('REFUSING TO CREATE OBJECT FOR %s' % cls_name)
            raise
```